# How to kill a process tree programmatically on Linux using C

Tags: c, linux, process, tree, kill

I am trying to write a function that spawns a child process, lets it run for a certain amount of time and then kills it if it hasn't finished:

```c
int sysExecTimeout(const char * exePath, int timeoutSec);
```

In the function, I use `fork` and `execl` to spawn the child, and, when it times out, I use `kill(pid, SIGTERM)` and `kill(pid, SIGKILL)` after 2 seconds, to ensure the child dies:

```c
pid_t pid = fork();

if(pid == 0) {
    execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", exePath);
    exit(127);
} else if(pid != -1) {
    // timeout code
    if(timeout) {
        kill(pid, SIGTERM);
        sleep(2);
        kill(pid, SIGKILL);
    }
}
```

I am using Linux, and it seems that when a parent process dies, the child is not killed automatically. So the two `kill` calls will just kill the `/bin/sh` process and leave the `exePath` command running, since it is  a child process of `/bin/sh`.

I am trying to write the `sysExecTimeout` function such that it kills the entire process tree rooted at `pid`, where `pid` is the PID from `pid = fork()`

I need this because the `exePath` command will spawn other commands, which can also spawn other commands, which could get stuck and consume resources.

I do not have control over the `exePath` binaries/scripts that get executed, so I cannot write my own parent-dies-so-kill-the-children logic in them.

I tried using `kill(0, SIGTERM)`, which almost did the job, except it also killed my own process :)

I am wondering if there is a flag I can turn on programatically in C that says "hey man, when I die, take all my children and kill them, and repeat recursively for their children" such that the entire process tree started from that program dies (assuming the PID/PPID chain can be followed).

I could use that flag here:

```c
if(pid == 0) {
    turnOnRecursiveDeathFlag();

    system(exePath);
    //execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", exePath);
    exit(127);
}
```

Is there a way to do that? I've been searching for a while, but all I can find are hacks using `ps -ef`, or modifying the children processes that you are running etc.

Comment: `} else if(pid == -1) {` : this indicates a problem with `fork()`, not the child process..

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was a typo :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use setpgid in the child to set its GPID equal to its own PID. The parent then can kill(-pid,...) to signal the entire group.

```
pid_t pid = fork();

if(pid == 0) {
    setpgid(0, 0);
    execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", exePath);
    exit(127);
} else if(pid == -1) {
    // timeout code
    if(timeout) {
        kill(-pid, SIGTERM);
        sleep(2);
        kill(-pid, SIGKILL);
    }
}
```

That should do it.

One more thing, when you spawn a shell, make sure it doesn't enable job control. Otherwise, it will create its own process groups. Your "/bin/sh -c" is fine.

Comment: Great, this seems to work, thank you! I'm not sure what the deal with process group IDs is (is that simply the GID of a process?), but I am looking into it.

Comment: Btw, since I can't edit your post, you should change setgpid to setpgid, which seems to be the correct name.

Comment: I fixed it for him @AlinTomescu... or i guess its being reviewed